# Как определить, имя функции или что используются две одинаковые функции?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!

Есть рабочий код, сначала фильтрует пот выборку делает:

```
function query(collection,select,filterIn) { 
  return select(filterIn(collection));
} 

function select(aruments[0],arguments[1],...){
 return function(collection){***}                    
   }  

function filterIn(aruments[0],arguments[1]){
 return function(collection){***}                    
   }
```

`friends` - массив из объектов;

`select`  - функция, аргументами которой являются поля объектов в массиве `friends`, которые надо вывести;

`filterIn` - функция, которая фильтрует объекты в массиве `friends`

вот код, который изменять нельзя, кроме как добавлять новые функции в качестве аргументов функции `query` (количество функций и их порядок неизвестен):

```
lib.query(
    friends,
    lib.select('name', 'gender', 'email'),
    lib.filterIn('favoriteFruit', ['Яблоко', 'Картофель']),
    lib.select('favoriteFruit',gender)
  );
```

Как изменить функцию query так, чтобы сначала `filterIn`,а потом `select` вызывались, и аргументы функции `query` были в неявном виде(т.е. код ниже)???

```
function query(collection) { 
  //правильный код

}
```

Comment: что вы имеете в виду под обьеденить функции ?

Comment: две одинаковые функции но с разными аргументами, должна поучиться одна с аргументами из пересечения двух

Comment: сделайте пример какой-то, ато не понятно чтоимеется в виду

Comment: изменил вопрос для понимания